# Python Simple DES encrypt/decrypt program "ValueError MAC check failed" issue

Tags: python, encryption-symmetric, des

I'm having quite the difficulty understanding what's wrong here, does anyone have the knowledge to decipher what this error message means and potentially how to fix the issue?

'''

```
from Crypto.Cipher import DES

def DESenc():
    key = b'password'
    message = b'i like beans'
    cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_EAX)
    ciphertext, tag = cipher.encrypt_and_digest(message)

    file_out = open("encrypted.bin", "wb")
    [ file_out.write(x) for x in (cipher.nonce, tag, ciphertext) ]
    file_out.close()

def DESdec():
    file_in = open("encrypted.bin", "rb")
    nonce, tag, ciphertext = [ file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 16, -1) ]
    key = b'password'

    cipher = DES.new(key, DES.MODE_EAX, nonce=nonce)
    data = cipher.decrypt_and_verify(ciphertext, tag)

    print(data.decode('ascii'))

DESenc()
DESdec()
```

'''

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, the tag size corresponds by default to the block size of the algorithm ([here](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html?highlight=encrypt_and_digest#eax-mode-1)), which is 8 bytes for DES (and not 16 bytes as e.g. for AES).
Therefore, during decryption

```py
nonce, tag, ciphertext = [ file_in.read(x) for x in (16, 8, -1) ]
```

must be applied. Then decryption works.

Alternatively, the tag size can be set explicitly (but for the parameters used, DES/EAX, 8 bytes is the maximum tag size).

Note that DES is deprecated and insecure. Today's standard is AES.